# Annual group means with uneven groups in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

Say I have the following data:

```
library(dplyr)
year <- rep(c(1,2,2,3,4,4,5),3)
group <- c(rep(1,7),rep(2,7),rep(3,7))
v1 <- rep(c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6),3)
v2 <- rep(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),3)
df <- data.frame(year,group,v1,v2)
```

I would like rolling annual group means for each variable, so that I end up with unique group-year means that take all previous years into account.

I know that this will give me annual group means:

```
gm <- df %>% 
    group_by(group, year) %>% 
    summarise_each(funs(mean))
```

But this doesn't consider all previous years. I need each group-year to include all previous group-years, and (importantly) the length of each group-year is ragged, so I cannot just take annual means and then `group_by()` each group and do a rolling mean over annual means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try

```
library(dplyr)
Un1 <- unique(df$year)
lapply(seq_along(Un1), function(i) 
        df[df$year %in% Un1[seq(i)],] %>% 
        group_by(group) %>% 
        summarise_each(funs(mean), v1:v2)) %>% 
        setNames(., Un1) %>%
        bind_rows(., .id='year')
```

Comment: This is great, thanks! I just added in the year with `mutate(year = i)`.

Comment: @cigrainger  You can use the `.id` in `bind_rows` to get the 'year' column.

Comment: Great, thanks. I think this can be sped up (a concern for me) by using `filter(year %in% Un1[seq(i)])` after the `group_by` for the years instead of `[`. That way it's not searching over all rows each time.

Comment: @cigrainger  I used that specifically to expand the dataset.  With the `dplyr` framework, you may need to use `do` to implement that, but that will be slow again.